# How can I submit a hyperlink through a form to go along with a photo and title in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form for my model, `Article.rb` that has two fields, `photo` and `title`. My index page shows these photos and titles. When I submit my form, I want to also submit an associated hyperlink of the external url associated with that photo and title.

For example, I would like to be able submit for `:title` in my form:

```
<a href="http://cnn.com/2016/mafia-arrests/index.html/">Mafia Arrests</a>
```

and have it shown as "Mafia Arrests" with a link to the CNN url. However ideally I would like the entire Div to be able to be clicked and take the user to the external site.

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="article">
  <% @articles.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group| %>
    <div class="row">
       <% group.each do |article| %>
         <div class="col-md-4">
           <div class="artwork">
             <%= image_tag article.artwork.thumb %>
           </div>
           <div class="title">
         <%= article.title %> updated to: <%=(sanitize)article.title %>
           </div>
         </div>
       <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>

<p>
  <%= f.label :title %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :artwork %><br>
  <%= f.file_field :artwork %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you paste the index page html, just to see how you wrote from there..?

Comment: See above for index.html.erb and new.html.erb

Comment: Where is the `form` ? I want to see that too

Comment: from where that anchor link is coming  ? I am not clear what you want.. Your index page is showing an image and title text. But from where that anchor link is coming, I am not getting it

Comment: My website shows a :title and a :photo of various news stories from around the web. I want to be able to associate the url's of these news stories so that the people viewing my website can click on the div of the :title and :photo on my website and be taken to the external url.

Comment: Ok, so when you are submitting the form, you want to also store the external url in the DB right ?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  I just figured out that I can use <%= sanitize(article.title) %> and this will show :title as a hyperlink... but is there anyway to make the whole div clickable as a hyperlink? Thanks

Comment: so your title, inside a model is a hyper link, not just a text. I am trying to hard to understand you. Sorry if it is too many questions. Yes, you can make the div clickble. You need to show the anchor text as the image.. so anyone clicks in the image will be forwarded to the site, you have in href

Comment: Yes, right now I have changed the index.html.erb from the above to <%= sanitize(article.title) %> and this displays the title properly as a hyperlink... However, if possible, I would like to make the entire div, including the image a hyperlink, not just the title.

Comment: see what I said above.. :)

Comment: How do I show the anchor text as the image? I know how to do this manually with link_to but I don't know how to do it when the image is a part of table.

Comment: `link_to` supports _block_. so like `link_to path do <p> title</p> image_tag '..' end`

Comment: This can be added to the index.html.erb above? I have been trying and can't figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating an extra column in my database source:string which is the url of the external site that I am linking to. then simply,

```
<%= link_to image_tag(article.artwork.thumb), (article.source) %>
```